# Inequality proof help

Tags: inequality

I was doing some work and got stuck at a proposition I made to finish it... I just can't seem to find it anywhere... Here it goes: 
$$a,b>0,r>1\implies \sqrt[r]{a+b}\leq\sqrt[r]{a}+\sqrt[r]{b}. $$

I tried for a plenty of values of $a,b,r$ and it seems to work in all cases... I'd love to see a proof or some counterexamples! Thanks in advance!

Note: $a,b,r$ are real numbers

Comment: This is not research level. If $r$ is an integer, this is simple algebra. Otherwise, the keyword is "convexity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show that
$$
1\le \left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^{1/r}+\left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^{1/r}.
$$
But
$$
0<\frac{a}{a+b},\,\frac{b}{a+b}<1,
$$
and as $0<\dfrac{1}{r}<1$, then 
$$
\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^{1/r}>\frac{a}{a+b}\,\,\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\,
\left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^{1/r}>\frac{b}{a+b},
$$
and hence
$$
\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^{1/r}+\left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^{1/r}>
\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{a+b}=1.
$$

Comment: I think I've got it.. I proved that f is concave and that f(0) >= 0 which implies that f is subadditve, meaning that f(x+y) <= f(x) + f(y), am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You can raise both terms of the inequality to r. You get:

$(\sqrt[r]{a+b})^r \leq (\sqrt[r]{a}+\sqrt[r]{b})^r \implies a+b \leq (\sqrt[r]{a})^r + (\sqrt[r]{b})^r + positiveterms $

Comment: Thinking about it more, I am not sure how accurate is what I wrote above, for non-integer r. Yiorgos answer is more general. Mine is more straightforward, only if it is correct for non-integer r :)

Comment: I've thought about that one too, but I'd reckon you're using the binomial theorem there which is only for integer exponents... I'm not quite sure that for non-integer exponents the part $(\sqrt[r]{a})^r + (\sqrt[r]{b})^r would appear... at least I have never heard about this kind of generalization of the binomial theorem...